# Reduce the space between bars in Column Graph in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, graph, ssrs-2008-r2

I have 4 entities: a,b,c,d each displaying values for 3 years (year1, year2 and year 3)

The graph is a column graph. The problem is that there is too much space between the years and very little space between the entities.

I want to reduce space between years (which is series group) and increase space between entities (which is category group)

(My Graph displays Entities as category groups and Years as row index with label as Years)

[Here is an image of what is currently happening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_Po7ND9VtON292Q3lTakl5d0k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and possibly an image of the result so we may assist you. [See this for help in asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is the SSRS report. I only have the file.

Comment: My apologies, I confused your question with another. What are the properties in the "Horizontal Axis Properties" dialog box?

Comment: Axis type: Category, Sidemargins: Disabled, Interval:1, Intervaltype: Auto

Comment: Change Sidemargins to Auto. What is the result? Post a new image if necessary.

Comment: Link for the properties: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_Po7ND9VtOdlZONHJWS3NOclU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: not an image of the properties, but how does the chart look after that change?

Comment: on changing that, I get space in the beginning.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_Po7ND9VtON0J2ZERSSHl2OVE/view?usp=sharing